# Why Java records do not support inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, record

Today I hit a wall, when I was about to add new functionality to the app. I had a record with data, but I needed some extra values. Adding this to the record would not make sense, becouse for most cases they will not be used and would be nulls, so I thought inheritance, which made perfect sense in this situation. But there is a problem , becouse Java records do not support inheritance, so I ended up with rewriting record to ugly POJO class with final values and getters.

So my question is basictly - why no inheritance. I understand there is not multiple inheritance becouse it's messy and hard to control on some point, but we also have final classes that cannot be inherited, why couldn't w e have records and final records?

Comment: read about immutability pattern. One of the requirements is nonextendability - and records are immutable classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way of using Records with inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605794/is-there-any-way-of-using-records-with-inheritance)

Comment: If in one situation the record has this data and in the other one it doesn't maybe they are two different records with some shared properties, that can also be grouped

Comment: It’s always the same answer, for decades. Prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: The short answer: we *could* support record-to-record inheritance, and we explored this in the design phase.  We did not pursue this because the incremental complexity and incremental benefit seemed out of line (you allude to some of this with "messy and hard to control").  It is not impossible, but not a priority for now.  We may return to this in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the corresponding [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359):

> Records are implicitly final, and cannot be abstract. These restrictions emphasize that the API of a record is defined solely by its state description, and cannot be enhanced later by another class or record.

> The components of a record are implicitly final. This restriction embodies an immutable by default policy that is widely applicable for data aggregates.

The point is that *reducing* the realm of usage patterns, the compiler/JVM can do the sort of optimisations that the record concept is about.

Meaning: if you allow for subclassing, the runtime will have to deal with polymorphism. Which is *not* the intention behind records.

Comment: I think you are confusing records for value types.  The reason to restrict inheritance for value types is because layout polymorphism interferes with flattening, but that's not exactly what's going on with records.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly answer your question but your use-case can actually be implemented using a combination of records and interfaces, eg:

```java
public interface Base {
   String prop1();
}
public interface Extended extends Base {
   String prop2();
}
record BaseR(String prop1) implements Base { }
record ExtendedR(String prop1, String prop2) implements Extended { }
```

You'd code your "client" against the interfaces, which is an OO best practice anyway.  If you feel unhappy about duplicating `prop1` (and presumably other properties) in both records, you could use a single record with an overloaded constructor, as follows:

```java
record Record(String prop1, String prop2) implements Extended { 
    Record(String prop1) {
        this(prop1, null);
    }
}
```

This allows constructing instances reasonably cleanly:

```java
Base base = new Record("prop1");
Extended ext  = new Record("prop1", "prop2");
```

Since your client is coded against `Base` and `Extended` (it knows nothing about `Record`), there's no risk of it accessing unsupported properties.