# Parse JSON to Java records with fasterxml.jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, record

Java records can not - by design - inherit from another object (see [Why Java records do not support inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139939/why-java-records-do-not-support-inheritance)). So I wonder what would be the best way to achieve the following.

Given my JSON data contains objects that have some common data + unique data. For example, type, width and height are in all shapes, but depending on the type, they can have additional fields:

```
{
  "name": "testDrawing",
  "shapes": [
    {
      "type": "shapeA",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 200,
      "label": "test"
    },
    {
      "type": "shapeB",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 200,
      "length": 300
    },
    {
      "type": "shapeC",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 200,
      "url": "www.test.be",
      "color": "#FF2233"
    }
  ]
}
```

In "traditional" Java you would do this with

```
BaseShape with width and height
ShapeA extends BaseShape with label
ShapeB extends BaseShape with length
ShapeC extends BaseShape with URL and color
```

But I'm a bit stubborn and really would like to use records.

My solution now looks like this:

- No BaseShape
- The common fields are repeated in all records

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record Drawing(
        @JsonProperty("name")
        String name,

        @JsonProperty("shapes")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = TestDeserializer.class)
        List<Object> shapes // I don't like the Objects here... 
) {
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record ShapeA (
        @JsonProperty("type") String type,
        @JsonProperty("width") Integer width,
        @JsonProperty("height") Integer height,
        @JsonProperty("label") String label
) {
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record ShapeB(
        @JsonProperty("type") String type,
        @JsonProperty("width") Integer width,
        @JsonProperty("height") Integer height,
        @JsonProperty("length") Integer length
) {
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record ShapeC(
        @JsonProperty("type") String type,
        @JsonProperty("width") Integer width,
        @JsonProperty("height") Integer height,
        @JsonProperty("url") String url,
        @JsonProperty("color") String color
) {
}
```

I don't like repeated code and it's a bad practice... But in the end I can get this loaded with this helper class:

```
public class TestDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public List<Object> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        List<Object> rt = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        if (node instanceof ArrayNode array) {
            for (Iterator<JsonNode> it = array.elements(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                JsonNode childNode = it.next();
                rt.add(getShape(childNode));
            }
        } else {
            rt.add(getShape(node));
        }

        return rt;
    }

    private Object getShape(JsonNode node) {
        var type = node.get("type").asText();
        switch (type) {
            case "shapeA":
                return mapper.convertValue(node, ShapeA.class);
            case "shapeB":
                return mapper.convertValue(node, ShapeB.class);
            case "shapeC":
                return mapper.convertValue(node, ShapeC.class);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Shape could not be parsed");
        }
    }
}
```

And this test proves to be working OK:

```
@Test
    void fromJsonToJson() throws IOException, JSONException {
        File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/test.json").getFile());
        String jsonFromFile = Files.readString(f.toPath());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Drawing drawing = mapper.readValue(jsonFromFile, Drawing.class);
        String jsonFromObject = mapper.writeValueAsString(drawing);

        System.out.println("Original:\n" + jsonFromFile.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", ""));
        System.out.println("Generated:\n" + jsonFromObject);

        assertAll(
                //() -> assertEquals(jsonFromFile, jsonFromObject),
                () -> assertEquals("testDrawing", drawing.name()),
                () -> assertTrue(drawing.shapes().get(0) instanceof ShapeA),
                () -> assertTrue(drawing.shapes().get(1) instanceof ShapeB),
                () -> assertTrue(drawing.shapes().get(2) instanceof ShapeC)
        );
    }
```

What would be the best way to achieve this with the Jackson library and Java Records?

Extra sidenote: I will also need to be able to write back to JSON in the same format as the original.

Comment: if a json object contains a field that contains a "discriminator" you can setup your classes in a hierachy where the base class contains only that field (and all common fields) and have subclasses for each discriminator value. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance#2-per-class-annotations is an example of that. `@JsonSubTypes` defines the value to class mapping and `@JsonTypeInfo` defines the field name - or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394819/jackson-polymorphism-how-to-map-multiple-subtypes-to-the-same-class

Comment: indeed, but as far as I know that won't work on Java records as they can't extend from a base...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Records cannot inherit because they are intended to be a solid contract, but they can implement an interface. So you can do something like this with `JasonSubTypes` with Jackson 2.12 or above:

Models

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record Drawing(
        String name,
        List<BaseShape> shapes
) { }

// added benefit of interface here is it reminds you to have the default fields
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ShapeA.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ShapeB.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ShapeC.class)
})
public interface BaseShape {
    Integer width();
    Integer height();
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record ShapeA (
        Integer width,
        Integer height,
        String label
) implements BaseShape { }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record ShapeB(
        Integer width,
        Integer height,
        Integer length
) implements BaseShape { }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record ShapeC(
        Integer width,
        Integer height,
        String url,
        String color
) implements BaseShape { }
```

Test Class

```java
@Slf4j
class DemoTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperBuilder.getObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final String testString = objectMapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(
                        new Drawing(
                                "happy",
                                List.of(
                                        new ShapeA(1, 1, "happyShape"),
                                        new ShapeB(2, 2, 3),
                                        new ShapeC(2, 2, "www.shape.com/shape", "blue"
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                );

        log.info("From model to string {}", testString);

        Drawing drawing = objectMapper.readValue(testString, Drawing.class);

        log.info(
                "Captured types {}",
                drawing
                    .shapes()
                    .stream()
                    .map(s -> s.getClass().getName())
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        );

        log.info(
                "From string back to model then again to string {}",
                objectMapper
                    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                    .writeValueAsString(drawing)
        );
    }

}
```

Here's the test log output:

```
17:06:41.293 [Test worker] INFO com.demo.DemoTest - From model to string {
  "name" : "happy",
  "shapes" : [ {
    "width" : 1,
    "height" : 1,
    "label" : "happyShape"
  }, {
    "width" : 2,
    "height" : 2,
    "length" : 3
  }, {
    "width" : 2,
    "height" : 2,
    "url" : "www.shape.com/shape",
    "color" : "blue"
  } ]
}
17:06:41.353 [Test worker] INFO com.demo.DemoTest - Captured types [com.demo.DemoTest$ShapeB, com.demo.DemoTest$ShapeA, com.demo.DemoTest$ShapeC]
17:06:41.354 [Test worker] INFO com.demo.DemoTest - From string back to model then again to string {
  "name" : "happy",
  "shapes" : [ {
    "width" : 1,
    "height" : 1,
    "label" : "happyShape"
  }, {
    "width" : 2,
    "height" : 2,
    "length" : 3
  }, {
    "width" : 2,
    "height" : 2,
    "url" : "www.shape.com/shape",
    "color" : "blue"
  } ]
}
```

Note that you can add the `type` field as a `name` property of the `@JsonSubTypes.Type` annotation, but this works with or without discriminator as long as the fields in your records are never exactly the same.

You can read more about `JsonSubtypes` [**here**](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-most-wanted-1-5-deduction-based-polymorphism-c7fb51db7818).

Comment: You can add the type field as a `name` property in the `@JsonSubTypes.Type` annotation, but this works with or without discriminator as long as the fields in your records are never exactly the same

Comment: wow, really like this approach! thanks for your very detailed explanation and test case!!!