# How to create a method that returns generics with incompatible bounds?

Tags: java, parsing, generics

Sorry for this noob Java question

---

I am trying to write a parser for the String representation of an Object of type T

T could be

- String
- ArrayList<T>
- LinkedHashMap<String, T>

I have used `toString()` to convert it into a String, example strings are like

```
"a"  
"{foo=bar}"  
"[foo, bar]"  
"[{foo1=bar1}, {foo2=bar2}]"
"{a=[a1, a2], b=b1, c={key:val}}"
```

Because the parsed result could be of various type, I am trying to make the parser return a generic type

I tried something like

```
private <T extends String & LinkedHashMap<String, T> & ArrayList<T>> T parse(String s)
throws ParseException {

    if (s.charAt(0) != '{' && s.charAt(0) != '[') {
      return s;
    } else if (s.charAt(0) == '{') {
      LinkedHashMap<String, T> res = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      for (String entry : s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(", ")) {
        String[] data = entry.split("=");
        res.put(data[0], parse(data[1]));
      }
      return res;
    } else if (s.charAt(0) == '[') {
      ArrayList<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String data : s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(", ")) {
        res.add(parse(data));
      }
      return res;
    } else {
      throw new ParseException(...);
    }

}
```

And got errors like

```
incompatible types:
   String cannot be converted to T
   LinkedHashMap<String,T> cannot be converted to T
   ArrayList<T> cannot be converted to T
```

How do I make it work?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `&` means "and" not "or"

Comment: What's the point of `T` in this pseudocode? What does it do that `Object` could not?

Comment: I think for generics & was used for [multiple bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)?

Comment: Multiple bounds means "extends A and B" not "extends A or B"

Comment: Having a return type that could be a String or a List or a Map doesn't work they way you intend. How would the compiler know what type to assign it to? It can't as it doesn't know the value, so all it knows is that an `Object` would be returned - and that's the only return type you can have in that method. - Suppose that method _would_ be possible: how would the compiler know the following is wrong? `String parsed = parse ("[{foo1=bar1}, {foo2=bar2}]");`

Comment: As for the `&`: as shmosel already stated that means "and". Additionally, only interfaces are allowed after the `&` so using `String & ArrayList` would not be possible. Why? Because Java doesn't support multiple inheritance so no class could ever extend both `String` and `ArrayList`. You could, however, do something like this: `T extends Collection<X> & Comparable<X>` to state "the return type is a collection of X that also implements the `Comparable` interface". That's what multiple bounds are used for.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The String comes from a fileReader which loads a yaml. I turned each field back to String to support Macro insertion, and then was unable to revert it back to the old type...

As someone coming from python, who's used to messy types and handy methods like eval, I felt pretty awkward about how to turn them back into their original String/List/Map type. Do you have any tips on that?

Comment: If you can commit to supplying a valid JSON then you can easily achieve this with the Jackson Library and JSON subtypes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891785/12302982

Otherwise you will have to develop your own parsing library for your non standard inputs. You will still need to bind the return to some sort of type or just return object and cast the object to whatever you need later on. Alternatively make your parser call the method that needs this data instead of calling the parser from the method.