# Nested immutable classes with records

Tags: java, immutability, record, java-17

Consider the below arrangement:

```
interface Message<T> {
    T getBody();
}

record SenderAwareMessage<T>(T body, Sender sender) implements Message<T> {
    @Override
    public T getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}

record PriorityMessage<T>(T body, Sender sender, int priority) extends SenderAwareMessage<T> {
    // cannot extend another record
}
```

I have 2 concrete implementations here. I want to avoid mutability but at the same time need more configurability at least to extend an existing record. I have went through the documentation, however the usage of record is very limited.

Is there any way I can achieve this scenario with records / any third party libraries?
I tried immutables, but it seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Records cant extend anything else, because they already extend Record. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63615514/10671013

Comment: Learn the purpose of `record`: https://openjdk.org/jeps/395

Comment: Then there is no choice but to go with Immutables / Lombok?

Comment: There is no need for one record to extend the other. If you want abstraction, that’s what the interface is for. Just let `Message` declare `sender()`, as it is common to all your implementation anyway. And I recommend renaming `getBody` to `body`, then you don’t need duplicate method declarations.